# Why does MersenneTwister seem to generate different sequences for the same seed?

Tags: random, julia, random-seed

Executing:

```
using Random

rng1 = MersenneTwister(42)
rng2 = MersenneTwister(42)

v = [ x for _ = 1:4, x = rand(rng1) ]
w = [ rand(rng2) for _ = 1:4 ]

print("$(v)\n$(w)\n")
```

generates the following output:

> [0.533183, 0.533183, 0.533183, 0.533183]
>   [0.533183, 0.454029, 0.0176868, 0.172933]

Shouldn't the two sequences be the same? What am I missing?

I get identical results on multiple systems, and with no regard to whether I create `v` first or `w`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see, all the elements of v are the same. The list comprehension you are using to construct v only evaluates `rand(rng1)` once and then copies the same value 4 times.

The problem is not the random number generator but the list comprehension.